# I am trying to display a JPEG image in java

Tags: java, swing

I have an assignment that I am doing where I am supposed to implement and design an application that plays a game called catch the creature.  Have the creature appear at a random location then disappear and reappear somewhere else.  The goal is to "catch" the creature by clicking the creature with a mouse button.  Record the number of times the creature is caught.

I need help just displaying the creature which is an JPEG of a pikachu, I have tried a few things but none of them work.  Any help is appreciated thank you!

Main Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;



public class Catch_The_Creature 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Catch the Creature");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Creature panel = new Creature();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Catch Pikachu!");



    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Creature Code:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.util.Random;  

import javax.swing.*; 

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class Creature extends JPanel 
{
private final int WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 300;
private final int DELAY=20, IMAGE_SIZE = 60;

private ImageIcon image;
private int pikachuX, pikachuY;
private int x, y;  
private int catchCount=0;  
private static Random generator = new Random();  
private Timer time;
private ActionListener updater;
private JLabel countLabel;

public Creature()  
{  
    image = new ImageIcon("image/pikachu.jpg");
    time =  new Timer(DELAY,  updater);

    addMouseListener ((MouseListener) new MouseClickedListener());  
    setBackground (Color.green);  


    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1900,1000));
    time.start();


}  

public boolean point(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == pikachuX  && y == pikachuY)
    {
        catchCount++;  
        return true;  
    } 

    return false;  
}  

public int getCatchCount()  
{  
    return catchCount;  
}  

private class MouseClickedListener extends MouseAdapter  
{  
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
       {  
           point(event.getX(), event.getY());  
       }

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{  
    super.paintComponent(page);  
    page.drawImage(image.getImage(),WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    page.drawString("Pikachus Captured: " + catchCount, 10, 35);  
    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,35));



}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

    time.setDelay(1000); 

    x += pikachuX;  
    y += pikachuY;  

    if (x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)  
        pikachuX = pikachuX * -1;  

    if (y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)  
        pikachuY = pikachuY * -1;  


    repaint();  

} 


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0){}




}
```

Comment: Where is the jpeg file located? You might need to use  the getClass().getResourceAsStream method.

Comment: Are you having trouble writing code to actually place the image on the screen, or is it a problem with the image not loading? Because I don't see any code that places your image. I may just be blind

Comment: I just have it in my downloads folder but when i turn it in it will be in the program folder itself, but before i can do that i just need it to display before i can see if anything else is wrong.

Comment: Where is the code, you're using to load the image on the screen?

Comment: I was using page.drawImage("pikachu.jpg",x, y,page); but it was not working

Comment: Look at my answer. It just a problem with your image file location. You should have a file structure like I have it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you ever add the `ImageIcon` to the panel or tell it to paint in the `paintComponent()` method.

**First solution** [Preferred]: Add `ImageIcon` to the panel.  In the constructor

```
super.add(image);
```

Make sure you use the correct layout (probably a null or absolute layout) and that you update the coordinates of the `ImageIcon` itself, not just some member variables.

**Second solution**: Paint the `ImageIcon` in the `paintComponent()` method.  This is probably discouraged because it goes against the general Swing principles.

Comment: What would be the correct way to ti implement the second solution I put page.paintImage(image,x, y,page); in the paintComponent but i wont compile.

Comment: You would use `Graphics.drawImage(..)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image, int, int, java.awt.image.ImageObserver)

Comment: doesnt compile for me

Comment: Are you passing in the `ImageIcon`?  If so then I would encourage you to read the link I posted.  The `drawImage()` method takes an `Image`, not an `ImageIcon`.  You should call it using `page.drawImage(image.getImage(), pikachuX, pikachuY, null);`.  Keep in mind this uses x and y as the top left corner to draw at.  I mention this because you are checking the exact coordinates against the mouse click in your `point` method.  This means only clicking on the exact pixel in the top left corner of the image will count as a capture.  You should probably implement a hit zone.

Comment: I edited the code so it compiles now but still does not display a my jpeg.  I am still just clueless of what i could be doing wrong.

Comment: You should try the other answers partial solution and use a `BufferedImage` instead.  This should throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Image file is in the right directory. If you're running from netbeans or eclipse your file structure should look like this

```
ProjectRoot
         src
         bin
         image
             pikachu.jpeg
```

Since you are using `"image/pikachu.png"`, you image filder should be a child of the project root folder as that's where the IDE will first search fore your file path

**Edit:** To draw image. Instead of using ImageIcon, use BufferedImage

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read("image/pikachu.jpeg");
} catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{  
    super.paintComponent(page);  
    page.drawImage(image, x, y, heightYouWant, widthYouWant, this);
    page.drawString("Pikachus Captured: " + catchCount, 10, 35);  
    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,35));

}
```

Comment: so i should put the image in the program file?  It wont read it from anywhere else?

Comment: You need to use the absolute path if you want to do that. I would just put it in the project folder.

Comment: well i still need a correct way of displaying the picture disrvptor told me super.add(image); in the contructor but then it asks to chage ImageIcon image to Component image. So im still stuck on how to actually display the image

Comment: @peeskillet, +1. But it is preferable to use `ImageIO.read(file)` and `BufferedImage` instead of `ImageIcon` for this context.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do was put values on where I wanted the picture to start at in the constructor.

```
public Creature()  
{  

    image = new ImageIcon ("pikachu.png");
    time =  new Timer(DELAY,  updater);

    x = 0;
    y = 50;

    addMouseListener ((MouseListener) new MouseClickedListener());  
    setBackground (Color.green);  



    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1900,1000));
    time.start();


}
```

While still using an Image Icon and still paint the image in the paint component.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{  
    super.paintComponent(page);  
    image.paintIcon (this, page, x, y); 
    page.drawString("Pikachus Captured: " + catchCount, 10, 35);  
    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,35));
}
```